# JSR 303 validation messages not showing (Jboss 7+primefaces 3.3)

Tags: jboss, primefaces, bean-validation

Hi I have this forms that isn't showing 
The validation messages. I belive I have done about everything right.

In the JPA entity

```
@NotEmpty(message="{not_empty}")
Private String studentNo;
```

In the ValidationMessages.properties which is inside the classes when the war is deployed ,I have
    Not_empty=Field is required

In the xhtml,
I have a 
    
I have also configured the message-bundle in the faces-config pointing to the Validation messages.

I believe I have done  everything,still the validation message does not show when validation fails.

Comment: please post the relevant part of your xhtml

Comment: @Kostja: please don't be upset. I have not yet applied your fix. Right now I am quite far from my dev. env. I will let you know in the next 15 hours.

Comment: no problem, just a standard help vampire precaution ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command button  , I added update="@Form" to it. So when the validation failed , it showed up the validation messages.
    
silly me!

Comment: glad you got it working. As you haven't posted the relevant xhtml parts, there was no way for me to know ;) I'll delete my answer as irrelevant